# What's the best way to increment time?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I want to add time given by user to another time and increment it for n number of times

```
start_time = '7:00' #these values will be taken as string by user
hour_time = '0:30'
increment_var = 5

time_var = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
difference_time = datetime.strptime(hour_time, '%H:%M')

time_var2 = difference_time.time()
```

Tried this

```
timed = timedelta(
    hours=time_var2.hour, minutes=time_var2.minute)

for num in range(increment_var):
    diffrence = time_var + timed
    print(diffrence)
```

And it gives me

```
1900-01-01 07:30:00
1900-01-01 07:30:00
1900-01-01 07:30:00
1900-01-01 07:30:00
1900-01-01 07:30:00
```

While I'm expecting something like

```
1900-01-01 07:30:00
1900-01-01 08:00:00
1900-01-01 08:30:00
1900-01-01 09:00:00
1900-01-01 09:30:00
```

And same results with

```
for num in range(increment_var):
    timed = timedelta(hours=time_var2.hour,
                      minutes=time_var2.minute)
    difference = time_var + timed
    print(difference)
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first 2 time points to be the same? You have `1900-01-01 07:30:00` twice in your expected output, then it starts incrementing

Comment: Anyway, the reason that nothing increments at all is because `time_var` never gets altered, so you just keep adding the increment to the same base value. On each loop you need `time_var = time_var + timed`

Comment: @roganjosh I've edited the question. That was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see why this code below works?

```
for num in range(increment_var):
    timed = timedelta(hours=time_var2.hour,
                      minutes=time_var2.minute)
    time_var = time_var + timed
    print(time_var)
```

Comment: Yeah I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't update time in the for loop

```
for num in range(increment_var + 1):
    print(time_var)
    time_var += timed
```